# Can I use a package with a different distribution for which it was made?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, realsense-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I want to use a realsense camera with ROS. The package for this can be found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/realsense2_camera). The problem/question I have is, can I use this with ROS melodic, even thought in the package page is says it was made for indigo and kinetic? To my understanding, if there have not been any huge changes between to different ROS distributions, the package should work properly with newer distributions. Additionally, I'm installing the package from source, so I thought it should work.

I followed the steps for the installation, found [here](https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense#step-3-install-intel-realsense-ros-from-sources). However, after I did, ROS does not see the package. I write "rosrun real" followed by a double tab, to show packages that start with this name, but nothing. I also wrote down the whole name, with no results.

Any sugestions/ideas? Am I just not installing from source the package correctly (I have limited experience with this)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298268/can-i-use-a-package-with-a-different-distribution-for-which-it-was-made?/) by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2018-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-23**:
If you have any errors please update your question with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can use packages that were written for another distribution of ROS than the one that you're currently using. You will most likely need to download the source and compile it yourself vs using `apt`. Once you compile it, then source your `setup.bash` with

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
source devel/setup.bash
```

Note: you may run into issues using a package that's meant for one distribution of ROS on another, but you may not.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2018-07-24**:
Hmm this is weird. I thought I tried this already. I attempted to do it again today and it worked. I guess after to much time working on it yesterday, I confused my self. In any case, thanks. It is up and running now.